# Constructing 3D image from center points and radius data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I have to construct a 3D image of spherical particles using python array operations. The data I have is center points and radius of spherical particles in `(x,y,z,r)` format. Where `x,y,z,r` are in the form of arrays of length 55000. When I do 3D plotting of these coordinates using `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d` the structure looks like as one shown in figure.[image: Figure]

Can you suggest a good way to make 3D image using `numpy` or `scipy.ndimage` image processing tools. If not possible is there any alternative method to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can compute the convex hull and plot that, or compute which points lie on the convex hull and plot those.  You can also fit a cylinder to your data and plot that.  We'll need a bit more guidance on the required outcome.